# How to use owl carousel in bootstrap modal

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, owl-carousel

I use owl carousel in bootstrap. But when I use it in bootstrap modal, it does not work properly. How I solve this problem, please help me...

Here the code:

```
jQuery('.portfolio-modal-active').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: false,
    margin: 0,
    dots: true,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    touchDrag: false,
    mouseDrag: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 4000,
    smartSpeed: 2000,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
        }
    }
})
```

Modal body is:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="portfolio-modal-active">
                <div class="portfolio-slider-item">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/img/home-slider/slider_1.jpg" alt="Slider Image" />
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-slider-item">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/img/home-slider/slider_2.jpg" alt="Slider Image" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```